# I can't get PowerShell to cast as int correctly

Tags: loops, powershell, csv, casting

I am currently importing a [CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) file which has a column that is all numbers. I am attempting to cast it as an int and only pull ones that are greater than 100. I have manually gone through this CSV file, and I can confirm that there are three rows with a greater-than-100% value. However, this always returns 0. What am I doing wrong?

```
$percentTooLarge = Import-Csv path\file.csv | Foreach-Object { $_.SumHoldingPercent = $_.SumHoldingPercent -as [int]; $_ } | Where-Object { $_.SumHoldingPercent -gt 100 } | Measure-Object
$numPercentTooLarge = $percentTooLarge.Count
```

Comment: What's the value of SumHoldingPercent in the file, '100' or '100%'?

Comment: some examples from the file 99.99413625, 100.0000006, 99.9999999

Comment: and as i type that, i'm assuming my problem is casting as an int, instead of float

Comment: Casting to Int should succeed though it will round your numbers. Remove the variable assignment and the call to Measure-Object, what's the result?

Comment: i dont know. i can tell you if i cast as float, it works perfectly

Comment: What do you get for this: Import-Csv path\file.csv | Foreach-Object { $_.SumHoldingPercent -as [int] }

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because of the way compare operators work in PowerShell, this should do the trick:

```
$percentTooLarge = Import-Csv path\file.csv | 
    Where-Object { 100 -lt $_.SumHoldingPercent} | 
    Measure-Object
```

Basically, PowerShell, when you compare things, tries to convert right to the type of left. If you put a value from ipcsv first - left will be a string. If you put a numeric first - it will convert the value from the CSV file to a number (it will be smart enough to keep the type big-enough ;))

I tested with this code:

```
@"
foo,bar,percent
alfa,beta,120.5
beta,gamma,99.9
foo,bar,30.4
works,cool,120.7
"@ | ConvertFrom-Csv | where { 100 -lt $_.percent }
```

... and the results seems OK.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your conversation with @Shay Levy, I would use:

```
[System.Globalization.CultureInfo] $culture = "en-us"
```

So you can try something like :

```
([decimal]::parse($_.SumHoldingPercent ,$culture)) -gt 100
```